# Basis change between orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to got from an orthonormal basis to another.

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1)=av_1+bv_2$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-1,1)=cv_1+dv_2$$

I know that $<v_1\cdot v_2>=0$ and $<v_1\cdot v_1> =1$ and $<v_2\cdot v_2> =1$

So

$$a^2v_1^2+b^2v^2=1\Rightarrow a^2+b^2=1$$

$$c^2v_1^2+d^2v^2=1\Rightarrow c^2+d^2=1$$

$$acv_1^2+bd^2v^2=0\Rightarrow ac+bd=0$$

How can I find $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: Take $a=\cos\theta$ ($\theta$ could be anything), then $b=\pm\sin\theta$ is a solution to $a^2+b^2=1$; $ac+bd=0\implies ac=-bd\implies c\cos\theta=\mp d\sin\theta$ so $c=\sin\theta$ and $d=\mp\cos\theta$

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to solve for the entries in the change-of-basis matrix directly, try mapping both bases to the standard basis and the composing these maps. This is particularly simple because the change-of-basis matrices are orthogonal, so you only need to transpose to compute the inverse. It looks like you’re trying to find the change of basis matrix that converts to $(v_1,v_2)$-coordinates, so if we’re working with *column* vectors as is usual, the change-of-basis matrix is $$\begin{bmatrix}v_1 & v_2\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2} & -\frac1{\sqrt2} \\ \frac1{\sqrt2} & \frac1{\sqrt2} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} v_1^T \\ v_2^T \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2} & -\frac1{\sqrt2} \\ \frac1{\sqrt2} & \frac1{\sqrt2} \end{bmatrix}.$$